# Consider sequence $(x_n)$ from $n=0$ to infinity given by $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=0.1+x_n^3$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider sequence $(x_n)$ from $n=0$ to $\infty$ given by $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=0.1+x_n^3$ for $n=0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$ . Prove that it converges.

I start by stating $0 < x_n < x_{n+1} < L$ but I'm not sure exactly how to find the limit $L$

Answer (score 2):

You could also argue that it is bounded, monotonically increasing (where these can be proved by induction). Then you can draw from the monotone convergence theorem and that pretty much proves it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Solve $x^3-x+.1=0$.  What does that tell you?

Comment: This would yield a fixed point for the recursion formula, towards which the sequence may converge, if it does, right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I tried to use Vieta's substitution to solve it, but I end up with no real root (negative discriminant for the sextic equation). Did I mess up somewhere? Because the sequence looks like it converges.

Answer (score 0):

start recursive,if  $x(0)=0$,then $x(1)=0.1+(x0)^3$ right?what is equal to  $x(2)?$ it is equal to $0.1+x(1)^3$  ,now  use  formula for  $x(1)$ and so on,finally use limit formula,for simplify final  denote $x(0)=k$